# How to use SQL AUTOINCREMENT primary keys without excessive round trips to the database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, auto-increment

Say I have 10 million Customer names each associated with one or more Addresses and I want to put the data in a SQL database.

I make a Customer table and an Address table.  The Customer table contains an autoincrement primary key.  Each Address entry points back to the Customer table with a foreign key.

Now, for each of 10 million records, I have to create a Customer record, insert it into the Customer table, then retrieve it again to get the autoincrement primary key that was assigned to it to use in a new Address entry.  20 million round trips.  Ugh.

Is there a better way besides resorting to GUIDs?

(I happen to be using SQLite with SQLAlchemy)

Comment: What format or platform is this customer and address data currently stored in?

Comment: It is hypothetical data.  My real use case is a complex dataset of user generated and simulated data.  There is no simple CSV to pull in, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure your Customer and Address objects to have a relation between them, you can simply insert them without worrying about the ID. SA knows that they're related and works out the FK details for you.

The careful reader will note that the SA Object Relational Tutorial [addresses this use case directly by creating a User object with a related Address](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship). I recognize the OP's actual problem is more complex, but the ORM tutorial seems like a great place to start. SA is a rockin' tool.

Note that you will still need to iterate over your 10M raw data objects, which may mean that your database's bulk-load tools might be a more effective solution, but that's a different approach.

Comment: This appears to be the best solution for SQLAlchemy.  Letting SA sort out the foreign keys is something like 10 times faster than trying to commit or flush after each customer insert and get the id explicitly.  However, even then SQLAlchemy is still *25 TIMES SLOWER* than using the python sqlite3 interface directly to do the individual inserts using lastrowid for the foreign key.

Comment: For those interested, or to recommend improvements, my test code and timing results are posted [http://pastebin.com/zCmzDraU](http://pastebin.com/zCmzDraU)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't using SA but an example to illustrate inserting rows in two tables in Sqlite3 and not doing a round trip.

Create a view that joins the two tables, then write an instead of trigger that handles the inserts and then insert into your view.  If you want to take this further it shouldn't be hard to modify SA to insert into your view.

```
create table customer (id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null);

create table address (id integer primary key autoincrement, customer_id integer references customer not null, street text);

create view customer_view as 
select customer.id as customer_id, customer.name, address.id as address_id, address.street
from customer 
inner join address on customer.id = address.id;

create trigger customer_view_insert_trg
instead of insert on customer_view begin
insert into customer (name) values (new.name);
insert into address (customer_id, street) values ((select last_insert_rowid()), new.street);
end;

insert into customer_view (name, street) values ('Joe', 'Main Street');
insert into customer_view (name, street) values ('Bill', 'Water Street');
```

---

```
sqlite> select * from customer;
1|Joe
2|Bill

sqlite> select * from address;
1|1|Main Street
2|2|Water Street
```

Comment: Haven't used triggers much, but they seem interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

> This routine returns the rowid of the most recent successful INSERT into the database from the database connection in the first argument.

And

> If the table has a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY then that column is another alias for the rowid.

Though that's a C/C++ interface function, the function also exists as an SQLite core function (which is, in fact, just a wrapper around the C/C++ one. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

Comment: Because there may be other clients modifying the table at the same time, so I cannot predict the autoincrement values.

Comment: In that case, do you have any other fields that can uniquely identify the data? I'm looking into the possibility of inserting into multiple tables at once in sqlite, but the majority of sites that seem to have discussion of that are blocked from the network I'm on, unfortunately...

Comment: @braddock: Oh wait, here we go. Found something that should work.

Comment: Making a call to "Last Insert Rowid" is still a round trip to the database.  Ideally I want to insert all my customers in a single SQL call.

Comment: Last I checked, SQLite doesn't allow you to do compound/multiple insertions in a single SQL statement anyway, so you'd be doing multiple SQL calls anyway. Unfortunately I don't think SQLite allows storing variables, either, so you could use `last_insert_rowid()` as the value for the foreign key in your first insert statement for the Addresses of the Customer you just inserted, and then `select <foreign key> from <your address table> where rowid=last_insert_rowid()` for the following Addresses. No "round trips" involved, as the data is all being processed by the SQL server.

Comment: The use of last_insert_rowid was helpful when using the python sqlite3 interface directly.  See my comment to khoxey.  After a lot of testing, it seems that my performance problems have more to do with the use of SQLAlchemy than sqlite database round trips.